# what does the "on" of a reducer do

Tags: angular, ngrx

I don't understand what the "on" of a reducer actually does

```
const loginReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(userActions.login, (state, {user}) => ({user, isLoading: true})),
```

it is especially this code that I do not understand :

```
(state, {user}) => ({user, isLoading: true})
```

Answer (score 2):

`on` is associations between actions and state changes. You can see it has 2 parameter, one is action type (userActions.login), when userActions.login trigged, the callback function also trigged.
(state, {user}) => ({user, isLoading: true}), it receive the current state and the updatedValue (user) then return a new state with `user` and `isLoading` updated new value. You can read more information here: https://ngrx.io/api/store/createReducer

Comment: how is the 'state' variable created? i mean how does it get the data?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [Understanding the magic behind StoreModule of NgRx (@ngrx/store)](https://indepth.dev/posts/1199/understanding-the-magic-behind-ngrx-store#createreducer-helper):

> The `on` functions are an alternative for using the `switch` statement. An `on` function can receive multiple action creators(results of `createAction`) and the actual reducer as the last argument.

The `on` function will return an object `{ types: string[], reducer: ActionReducer<S> }`, where `types` is the cumulation of each type of the provided `ActionCreator`(e.g `on(Action1, Action2, Action3, (state, action) => {})`) and `reducer` is a **pure function** which handles state changes based on the action and has this signature: `(state: T | undefined, action: V): T;`.

An `ActionCreator` looks like this:

```js
export interface ActionReducer<T, V extends Action = Action> {
  (state: T | undefined, action: V): T;
}
```

Internally, the `createReducer` function keeps track of actions and their reducers with the help of a [`Map` object](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/reducer_creator.ts#L109):

```js
export function createReducer<S, A extends Action = Action>(
  initialState: S,
  ...ons: ReducerTypes<S, ActionCreator[]>[]
): ActionReducer<S, A> {
  const map = new Map<string, OnReducer<S, ActionCreator[]>>();
  for (const on of ons) {
    /* ... populating the `map` */
  }

  return function (state: S = initialState, action: A): S {
    const reducer = map.get(action.type);
    return reducer ? reducer(state, action) : state;
  };
```

As you cans see, `createReducer` returns a function, so when a reducer of a certain slice of the store is invoked, with the help of closures, the reducer(the last argument of `on`) of the provided action will be retrieved and will be invoked too.

Comment: How does 'state' variable get its data?